# Oracle Cloud: Gradle in Compute Arm Instance: jcenter.bintray.com FORBIDDEN

Tags: cloud-computing

I'm trying to build some project on a free

```
Canonical-Ubuntu-20.04-aarch64-2021.10.15-0 (ARM machine)
```

for example launching

`./gradlew clean`

On this project:

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava

but I have some problems with the dependencies (seems all related to jcenter) for example

```
Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/javaparser/javaparser-symbol-solver-model/3.13.5/javaparser-symbol-solver-model-3.13.5.jar'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
```

Actually doing a ping to the URL:

```
ping jcenter.bintray.com
```

Is resolves as:

```
180.74.95.34.bc.googleusercontent.com (34.95.74.180)
```

Same problem with a wget (using --debug), so this is not related to certificate of JVM (I think):

```
<p>Your client does not have permission to get URL <code>/com/github/javaparser/javaparser-symbol-solver-model/3.13.5/javaparser-symbol-solver-model-3.13.5.jar</code> from this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
] done.
2021-12-09 10:05:50 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

And it seems SSL is correctly handled:

```
Initiating SSL handshake.
Handshake successful; connected socket 3 to SSL handle 0x0000aaaafdff9d80
certificate:
  subject: CN=*.bintray.com
  issuer:  CN=GeoTrust TLS DV RSA Mixed SHA256 2020 CA-1,O=DigiCert Inc,C=US
X509 certificate successfully verified and matches host jcenter.bintray.com
```

I can reach the URL with no problem from my machine.
VM Machine have a subnet with egress rule that allows all traffic for all ports.

I don't know IpTables but i try to see the configuration and I can't find nothing about a Rule to block this request (may be someone could help me on that).

```
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    InstanceServices  all  --  anywhere             link-local/16
```

I'm not a gradle expert nor a network expert so, i'm missing something i think....

BTW someone with the right reputation can create a tag **oracle-cloud-infrastructure**  :)?

Any hint is welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the issue was not related to VM configuration, but an external problem after one day the VM work fine and dependencies are downloaded without problem